# Is there a hook for a recursive minibuffer setup?

Tags: elisp, hooks, minibuffer

I have this code:

```cl
(minibuffer-with-setup-hook
    #'ivy--minibuffer-setup
  (read-from-minibuffer
   ;; ...
   ))
```

It works fine unless the code is called when already in the minibuffer. In that case `ivy--minibuffer-setup` isn't called.  Is there a way to achieve what I want: while in minibuffer, call `read-from-minibuffer` and call some code after the recursive minibuffer is entered?

Comment: Sounds like a bug.

Comment: Are you sure `minibuffer-with-setup-hook` isn't used when you start a recursive minibuffer? I think it is used for every minibuffer activation. Perhaps something on the hook raised an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it is this part of the `minibuffer-with-setup-hook` macro code?  It apparently removes the hook for recursive calls.

```el
(lambda ()
  ;; Clear out this hook so it does not interfere
  ;; with any recursive minibuffer usage.
  (remove-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook ,hook)
  (funcall ,fun))
```

Try doing without `minibuffer-with-setup-hook` and just doing the `add-hook` and `remove-hook` (at the end) yourself.

Comment: And don't forget to use `unwind-protect`!